# Same name string parameters with differ case were parsed into one string parameter by comma delimited

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, action

In Javascript request, I added two parameters with same name but different case

1. `*.setPostDataItem("FluentSearch", scope.search); (abc)`
2. `*.setPostDataItem("fluentSearch", scope.search); (abc)`

My server side code controller->action parsed it as

```
string FluentSearch = abc, abc
```

So at the server parameter we have at one string parameters duplicate value by comma delimited.

I expect that server should parse request and wrote them ones without comma.

Where and why does ASP.NET MVC pre-work same parameters twice by comma? Is it specific action executor before?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly; I also added as code some specific words in your explanation.
Formatting your code and question properly improves readability, so more people will understand what you're asking and will be more prone to answering.

Check the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Comment: Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could understand, it seems that client is sending two different parameters but server is treating them as one combining them as csv.

See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127030/1384239

Excerpt from answer

> It is entirely up to that authority on whether this stuff is
>   case-sensitive or not.
>
> In the case of C# and IIS, the backing store for the parsed query
>   string in the HttpRequest object is a 
>   System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection which happens to be
>   case-insensitive (by default).

Now looking at [name value collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2) it specifically says that

> The hash code provider dispenses hash codes for keys in the
>   NameValueCollection. The default hash code provider is the
>   CaseInsensitiveHashCodeProvider.

So it seems that it can be changed to become case sensitive. I did not try that. You might try that. This behavior should be same for query string parameters.

Comment: Great, thanks! Point out me please where can I see implementation of csv parser by default in asp.net mvc bounds? What implementation makes decision about combine two keys into one parameter separated by comma?

Comment: Please advise me